# Unable to launch

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to programming and face a problem: An assignment requires from students to open some files .java in eclipse. Trying to run these files, an error pops up: Unable to launch. I tried to change run configuration but I'm unable to change it. I appreciate any help, thank you [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dqjh.png)

Comment: Is this just a class with no main method? That might be the issue.

Comment: Looks like that class doesn't have a `main` method, and you have never run anything with a main. Your Run Configuration must specify a Main class that contains a main method.

Comment: You have a general project instead of a Java project (project folder is not decorated with a _j_), so the .java files will not be compiled (the Java editor icon is an outline _J_ instead of a regular _J_). Use _File > Open Projects from File System..._ and choose the _Practice Assingment Template_ directory (_Assingment_ seems to be misspelled and should probably be _Assignment_).